# Iteratively adding value to column of text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, for

I have a 3 column text file (XYZ coordinates) and I need to iteratively add constants to the first column while appending to the end of the original file. I have tried several options but this is the one that gives the clearest idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
awk ' { for ( i=-4; i<=4; i+=2 ) $1+=i }' coords.txt >> new_coords.txt
```

This command results in a blank new_coords.txt file. How do I go about getting the output of the for loop into the new text file?

**Minimal Input**

```
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

**Minimal Output**

```
0 5 6
3 8 9 
2 5 6 
5 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
6 5 6
9 8 9
8 5 6
11 8 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be one of the (rare) cases when it actually makes sense to put the loop outside of Awk:

```
$ for ((i=-4;i<=4;i+=2)); do awk -v i="$i" '{$1+=i} 1' Input; done
0 5 6
3 8 9
2 5 6
5 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
6 5 6
9 8 9
8 5 6
11 8 9
```

Otherwise:

```
$ awk '{a[NR] = $1; b[NR] = $2 FS $3} END{for(i=-4;i<=4;i+=2){for(j=1;j<=NR;j++) print a[j]+i, b[j]}}' Input 
0 5 6
3 8 9
2 5 6
5 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
6 5 6
9 8 9
8 5 6
11 8 9
```